# Red, White, and Blue probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a bag of M&M's with 10 red, 10 white, and 10 blue candies.   What is the probability that exactly n draws will be required to get at least one of each color?

Answer (score 3):

First let's assume that the last colour you collect is blue.
The first $n-1$ draws must result in only red and white candies, for which there are $20\choose n-1$ choices. However, we subtract the ${10\choose n-1}+{10\choose n-1}$ ways of having only red or only white candies. After that, there are $10$ choices for the final blue candy. 
Finally, multiply by $3$ to account for the different possibilities for the last colour. Thus there are
$$ \left({20\choose n-1}-2{10\choose n-1}\right)\cdot 10\cdot 3$$
good draw sequences out of a total of
$$30\choose n$$
possible draw sequences. Divide to obtain the probability.